# Xfce - GUI for File Compression?

Tags: gui, xfce, compression, zip

If I remember correctly, using Nautilus in Gnome, I could simply right-click on a file & select "compress".

Now I am using Thunar in Xfce & I can't find how to simply compress files...

I absolutely do not want any command-line solution!

Thanks for any suggestions & apologies if I missed something obvious!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can install `thunar-archive-plugin` from the software center or from the command-line by `sudo apt-get install thunar-archive-plugin`. It's a tiny install and when you next open Thunar and right-click on a file or folder, you'll see the `Create Archive ...` option:

[image: Thunar plugin]

On reflection, thunar-archive-plugin shoud be installed by default in [Xubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/xubuntu-desktop). So, you *should* see it in default Xubuntu or even if you install `xubuntu-desktop`.